# Azure SQL Database Sync Login Issue

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure, sql-data-sync

I wish to transfer data between two different databases on the same Azure SQL server (not managed instance). I have an admin account. When i goto setup Data Sync within the Azure portal i cannot see the tables after i created the Sync Group.

I followed the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell&view=azuresql#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities. The error i get is

> SqlError Number:18456, Message: Login failed.

Ill use the following as examples

MasterDatabaseName = Master

HUBDatabaseName = DatabaseSend

ChildDatabaseName = DatabaseRecieve

Azure SQL Server Admin = myname@mycompany.com

However this is where i think the error lies, I login to the Azure Data Portal as myname@mycompany.com and i created the Server and databases with this company email login, however if i look in the overview inside the Azure Portal of the SQL server my server admin name is CloudS******** where * = random letters and numbers

If i do a assigned roles check on my databases using the following code

> SELECT u.name AS UserName, u.type_desc AS UserType, r.name AS RoleName
> FROM sys.database_principals AS u LEFT JOIN sys.database_role_members
> AS rm ON rm.member_principal_id = u.principal_id LEFT JOIN
> sys.database_principals AS r ON r.principal_id = rm.role_principal_id
> WHERE
> u.type NOT IN('R', 'G') ORDER BY
> UserName
> , RoleName;

I get the Following for Master

| UserName | UserType | RoleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CloudS******** | SQL_USER | dbmanager |
| CloudS******** | SQL_USER | loginmanager |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_GROUP | dbmanager |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_GROUP | loginmanager |
| dbo | SQL_User | db_owner |

DatabaseSend

| UserName | UserType | RoleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_ddladmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_backupoperator |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_accessadmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_securityadmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_owner |
| dbo | SQL_User | db_owner |

DatabaseRecieve

| UserName | UserType | RoleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_ddladmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_backupoperator |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_accessadmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_securityadmin |
| myname@mycompany.com | EXTERNAL_USER | db_owner |
| dbo | SQL_User | db_owner |

If i try to add the user CloudS******** to DatabaseSend or DatabaseRecieve with CREATE USER i get the following error

> The login already has an account under a different user name.

If i try to add the role dbmanager or loginmanager to myname@mycompany.com in DatabaseSend or DatabaseRecieve i get

> Cannot alter the role 'dbmanger', because it does not exist or you do
> not have permission.

And if i try to add myname@mycompany.com to the role db_owner in Master i get the following error

> Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do
> not have permission.

Could some kind person please help this SQL Admin noob out? I think its because its not a uniform role across the databases, however i am unsure.

Comment: Check if the login myname@mycompany.com is the owner of the database. if so transfer the role to SA or a dedicated login for ownership and then create your user and add him to the correct roles.

Comment: myname@mycompany.com is the owner of both databases and admin.

Comment: Change the owner on the database and try again: 
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<database> TO sa;

Comment: Thanks Sporri I got it too work by turning off AAD Auth Only. Sucks kind of wanted the users to use MFA

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to turn off AAD Auth only and it worked.